# Joomla any action in Article Manager showing a blank page

Tags: joomla

I am facing a strange problem in Joomla Article Manager.

Any action (add, edit,..) on the page is showing a blank page.
For e.g if I click on "New" button it redirect the page to
`administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit` which is completely a blank page. Any suggestion/idea?

I have already tried to re-upload components/com_content, disable WYSIWYG Editor, etc. :(

Comment: try to turn on error_reporting and see what error it shows and paste it in your question.

Comment: have a look at the error log in your server and tells us what error it shows

Comment: Thank you guys! The issue is resolved. I disabled WYSIWYG editor component: JCE that was installed on the site and the issue is gone. I would suggest if anyone facing same issue, just try disabling your WYSIWYG editor (JCE, FCK, etc..) It worked for me :)